# Couchbase how to query an array

Tags: couchbase, sql++

If I have Couchbase documents that look like this:

```
{
  "history": {
    "id": "123",
    "date": "today",
    "status_history": [
      {
        "code": "0",
        "message": "success",
        "status": "complete"
      }
    ],
    "other": "other"
  }
}
```

If I want to get all the documents from today I can do something like `select * from 'my_bucket' where history.date = "today"`

But how can I get something like status from status_history that is in an array structure?

```
select * from 'my_bucket' where history.status_history. status?? = "complete"
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `[]` syntax for specific array elements, you can also use `ANY` and `ALL` if you want to make sure that any element (or all of them) satisfies some condition. For example:

```
select * from my_bucket 
where any s in status_history satisfies s.status = 'complete' end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can address array elements using `[]` syntax.

For instance:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM my_bucket h
WHERE h.status_history[0].status = 'complete'
```